# Helm sprig template pipe and/or negatate

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, sprig-template-functions

I'm trying to create my config map in helm using the following code:

```
 api: "{{ .Values.global.api }}",
 demo: {{ .Values.global.api | contains "demo" }},
 other: ....,
```

I would like to set `other` as true if Values.global.api NOT contains "demo" and "prod".
Something like

```
other: {{ .Values.global.api | NOT (contains "demo" AND contains "prod") }},
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Go `text/template` language, pipelines and function calls are equivalent and you can freely substitute in either direction

```
{{ x | f a b }}
{{ f a b (x) }}
```

You can't distribute a parameter across multiple functions as you're suggesting here; you need to repeat it (or put it into a local variable).  Looking through the catalog of [Sprig](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/) functions, I'm not sure there's any specific function that matches your needs that would make this simpler.  You have to spell it out:

```
demo: {{ not (and (contains "demo" .Values.global.api) (contains "prod" .Values.global.api)) }}
```

As I parenthetically suggested, you can use a local variable to shorten this a little:

```
{{- $api := .Values.global.api }}
api: {{ quote $api }}
demo: {{ not (and (contains "demo" $api) (contains "prod" $api)) }}
```